# How do I lookup a DataFrame with .loc by value in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I look up a dataframe of S&P 500 stock data, either by the company's name or symbol:

```
                 Company Symbol    Weight    Price   Chg     % Chg
4  Alphabet Inc. Class A  GOOGL  2.173993  2924.72 -8.38  (-0.29%)
```

Right now, I'm printing that using `print(df.loc[[4]])` as in my list Google is index number 4. I was wondering if there exists another `loc` command so that if the input is either the symbol or the name, the same thing will be printed. Below I have attached my current code:

```py
# Web-scraped S&P 500 data for 500+ US stocks.

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62'}

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' # Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

table1 = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover table-borderless table-sm'})

for row in table1.find_all('tr'):
    all_td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(all_td_tags) > 0:
        company = all_td_tags[1].text
        symbol = all_td_tags[2].text
        weight = all_td_tags[3].text
        price = all_td_tags[4].text
        chg = all_td_tags[5].text
        perChg = all_td_tags[6].text
        # print(company, '|', symbol, '|', weight, '|', price, '|', chg, '|', perChg)

df = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]
df.drop(['#'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
print(df.loc[[4]])
```

[Context: I'm trying to make a stock simulator game with S&P 500 data, which I have web-scraped from a host site.]

Comment: Recommend you make the stock symbol the index `df.set_index('Symbol')`. Now you can lookup-by-symbol simply with `df.loc['GOOGL']`. That's likely the most common case. Or to lookup-by-company-name with `df[df['Company'] == 'Name of Company']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find rows by:

```
df[df['Symbol'] == 'GOOGL']
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That seems to do it! If I may ask, how does your table turn out so organized? Did you install a plug-in or include a library?

Comment: Just ran it Jupiter notebook in PyCharm ide

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you make the stock symbol the index with `df.set_index('Symbol')`. Then you can do either:

#### Lookup-by-symbol

`df.loc['GOOGL']`

#### Lookup-by-company-name

`df[df['Company'] == 'Name of Company']`

(Probably looking up by Symbol is the common case. That's why you make it the index.)